# Google stacked column chart -how to create required json from mysql query results

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization

This is a question about creating json from MySQL query results. The json will be used in Google Chart.

I have not seen an explicit example of how to create json array from MySQL query results that can be used in Google ColumnChart where isStacked: true.

I have the ColumnChart without stacking working fine. That code is included below.  The chart shows card on x axis and values on y axis.

However, now I want to include a date value (year and month string) and put that on x axis instead, and then stack the cards within columns by date.

I am struggling with getting the json array into the pivoted / cross table format that Google appears to want (eg here [https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#stacked-bar-charts])

I suspect that i need to loop through the cards and create column headings from them similarly to how the row values are created

```
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['card']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['value']); 
    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
```

And instead of just have a single column for the cards as done for basic unstacked ColumnChart like this:

```
//define your DataTable columns here
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'card', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'value', 'type' => 'number')
);
```

Maybe do something like this:

```
//define your DataTable columns here
$table['cols'] = array(
// loop through query results to get cards and make column from each of them
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['card']);
    $cols[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
);
```

But then still not sure how the value is introduced into array.

Can anyone point me in right direction please?

**MySQL/php/json data source:**

```
<?php

//connect to database
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$hostname = "127.0.0.1"; 

//connection to the database
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to that");
mysql_select_db("sitrucp_ppcc");

//run query
$query = "select 
ca.name as 'card', 
count(a.id) as 'value' 
from activities a
join cards ca
on a.card_id = ca.id
group by 
ca.name
order by 
ca.name";  

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$table = array();
//define your DataTable columns here
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'card', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'value', 'type' => 'number')
);

// each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
// typecast all numbers to the appropriate type (int or float) as needed - otherwise they are input as strings
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['card']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['value']); 
    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

echo $jsonTable;


mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

**Google chart web page:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">   </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the chart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "activities_json_by_card.php",
                dataType:"json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

            //set chart options
            var options = {
                title: 'Card Activities',
                vAxis: {title: "Value"},
                hAxis: {title: "Cards"},
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                legend: { position: 'none' }
            };

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);

        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Div that will hold the chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).